# Lines not respecting padding of parent pane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestCoordinates extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Pane pane1 = new Pane();
        pane1.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        pane1.getChildren().addAll(pane);
        Point2D p1 = pane.localToParent(0, 0);
        Point2D p2 = pane.localToParent(50, 50);
        Line line = new Line(p1.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getX(), p2.getY());
        pane.getChildren().addAll(line);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane1));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I am trying to draw a line in the inner pane, but it seems to insist sticking into the outer pane:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you calling `localToParent(...)`?

Comment: I think the padding will only affect the computation of the min/max/pref sizes of the pane. The inner pane, `pane1` is still going to be positioned at the top left of the outer pane, `pane` (because that's what a `Pane` does). Try using a layout pane that manages its child nodes for the outer pane, e.g. `StackPane`, which will center the inner pane, or `HBox`, etc. The coordinate transformation really doesn't do anything for you, since the inner pane is going to be at (0,0) in the outer pane coordinates anyway (and even if not, it doesn't make sense anyway).